# Ruby-Watir Warning - Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ObsoleteElementError

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

Hey y'all I'm getting a warning running my watir test automation code and even though it works I want to address it.

> The Warning: 2020-02-12 08:35:47 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ObsoleteElementError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError (ensure the
>   driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.

The offending line of code:

```
iframe.select(:id => 'col0').wait_until(&:present?)
```

from this larger snippet.

```
 iframe = @b.iframe(:title => /Mass Delete/)
  iframe.wait_until(&:present?)
  if iframe.present?
    iframe.link(:visible_text => /Mass Delete #{type}/).click
    iframe.select(:id => 'col0').wait_until(&:present?)
    iframe.option(:text => /Owner Alias/).select
    iframe.option(:text => 'equals').select
    iframe.text_field(:id => "fval0").set user
    iframe.button(:title => "Search").click
  else
   raise "Unable to locate the Salesforce Iframe"
end
```

Here's the page html:

[Page Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIz0y.png)

I've tried using different locators to interact with that element but to no avail.

Comment: It might be a problem with Watir and a newer version of Selenium than what they initially tested against. A deprecation warning though, is a warning; not an error that blocks the test. Or is this warning also blocking your test from running?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. I've recently upgraded to both the latest stable watir and latest stable selenium. 

And correct, it is just a warning and does not stop the test from running. It just bugs me :/

Comment: Sorry, we've struggled to get a new Watir release out to address this. We're currently working on it.

Comment: Oh - that's great news. Is there a bug report available that I can follow to find out when this will be fixed?

Comment: The fix is already checked in (https://github.com/watir/watir/pull/867). We just need to figure out why some of the tests started failing (likely driver issues rather than Watir code). If you feel adventurous, you could run use the source directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be addressed in the next version of Watir - exact release date is TBD. In the short-term, you have a couple of options to hide the warning.

**Log to File**

I would suggest sending the Selenium logs to a file. This keeps it separated and still available if you happen to need it.

```
Selenium::WebDriver.logger.output = 'selenium.log'
```

**Ignore Warnings**

Usually you do not need the Selenium warnings as they should get addressed by Watir changes. Therefore you could change the Selenium logger to ignore warnings:

```
Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :error
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer!

Comment: I beleive if you become a lead to the WATIR team, everything will go smoothly. You are always available!

Comment: I included this line in my project but I don't find the file in my project directory. Where would this file be created?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, I would expect it to be in the root of the working directory. Note that the Selenium Logger is mostly forwarding to the [standard Ruby Logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html). Like the standard Logger, you can also provide a path for the file, which might help get the file to the right place.

Comment: Okay, it's not storing in the root directory. Anyway it's not taking WATIR warning into that file so it's useless for me.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, that will only store Selenium warnings. If you want to push the Watir warnings to file, you need the respective `Watir.logger.output = 'watir.log'`.

Comment: OH Great! That's what I want. Thanks.